# Converting a 16bit GeoTiff file as an 8bit JPEG file using python

Tags: python, geospatial, gdal

I am trying to convert a 16 bit 3-band RGB GeoTIFF file into an 8 bit 3-band JPEG file. It seems like the `gdal` library should work well for this. **My question is how do I specify the conversion to 8-bit output in the python gdal API, and how do I scale the values in that conversion? Also, how do I check to tell whether the output is 8-bit or 16-bit?**

The `gdal.Translate()` function should serve the purpose. However, the only example that I found which will rescale the values to 8 bit involves the C interface. The two posts below provide examples of this, but again they do not suit my purpose because they are not using the Python interface.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26249/how-to-convert-qgis-generated-tiff-images-into-jpg-jpeg-using-gdal-command-line/26252

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206537/geotiff-to-16-bit-tiff-png-or-bmp-image-for-heightmap/206786

The python code that I came up with is:

```
from osgeo import gdal
gdal.Translate(destName='test.jpg', srcDS='test.tif')
```

This will work, but I don't think the output is coverted to 8-bit or that the values are rescaled. Does anyone know how to apply those specific settings?

Note that this post below is very similar, but uses the `PIL` package. However the problem is that apparently `PIL` has trouble ingesting 16 bit images. When I tried this code I got errors about reading the data. Hence, I could not use this solution.

[converting tiff to jpeg in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870504/converting-tiff-to-jpeg-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use **options** like this

```
from osgeo import gdal

scale = '-scale min_val max_val'
options_list = [
    '-ot Byte',
    '-of JPEG',
    scale
] 
options_string = " ".join(options_list)

gdal.Translate('test.jpg',
               'test.tif',
               options=options_string)
```

Choose the min and max values you find suitable for your image as `min_val` and `max_val`

If you like to expand scaling to the entire range, you can simply skip min and max value and just use `scale = '-scale'`

Answer (score 2):

I think the gdal way is to use [`gdal.TranslateOptions()`](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#TranslateOptions).

```
from osgeo import gdal

translate_options = gdal.TranslateOptions(format='JPEG',
                                          outputType=gdal.GDT_Byte,
                                          scaleParams=[''],
                                          # scaleParams=[min_val, max_val],
                                          )

gdal.Translate(destName='test.jpg', srcDS='test.tif', options=translate_options)
```