# TIF to JPEG Conversion - No such file or directory

Tags: python, pycharm, python-imaging-library, jpeg, tiff

I am using this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870504/converting-tiff-to-jpeg-in-python) (answer by @user2019716) to convert .tif to .jpeg to use on the tensorflow object detection API. I have done the conversion before with no problems, but for some reason today, I receive a `No such file or directory: '__0.tif'` error and I don't understand why this is happening. I've checked the directory that I put in `C:/Users/name/Desktop/phantom80_labelImg/TIF/` and there are a list of `.tif` files starting from __0.tif to __34.tif. I know the code works because I have used it before, but I don't know why it is not reading file `.tif` files now.

Any suggestions?

```
import os
from PIL import Image

for infile in os.listdir("C:/Users/name/Desktop/phantom80_labelImg/TIF/"):
    print("file : " + infile)
    if infile[-3:] == "tif" or infile[-3:] == "bmp" :
       # print "is tif or bmp"
       outfile = infile[:-3] + "jpeg"
       im = Image.open(infile)
       print("new filename : " + outfile)
       out = im.convert("RGB")
       out.save(outfile, "JPEG", quality=90)
```

```
C:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\MaskRCNN_SpeCraft\python.exe C:/Users/name/z/MaskRCNN_SpeCraft/tif_to_jpeg.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/name/z/MaskRCNN_SpeCraft/tif_to_jpeg.py", line 12, in <module>
    im = Image.open(infile)
  File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\MaskRCNN_SpeCraft\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2891, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '__0.tif'
C:\Users\name\z\MaskRCNN_SpeCraft
file : __0.tif

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Replace the / in the path name with // Does that work?

Comment: @AdityaChavan No, I receive the same error.

Comment: For accessibility, please replace your code and errors as text.

Comment: Comment out the rest of the code and see if print(infile) line prints filenames

Comment: If you try to save to a full path rather than just a filename, does that work? i.e. instead of just `outfile` do `'C:/whatever/' + outfile`

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack, edited post.

Comment: I ended up changing my working directory to the specific folder and it worked. `os.chdir("C:/Users/name/Desktop/phantom80_labelImg/TIF/)`. Though I do not understand why I would have to change the working directory if I specifically indicate what which folder I want to pull the `.tif` from???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.listdir(dir)` only returns names of the files in that directory ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir)).

To open file you will need to get full file path. You can use `os.path.join` ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join))

```
root_dir = "C:/Users/name/Desktop/phantom80_labelImg/TIF/"
for filename in os.lisdir(root_dir):
    infile = os.path.join(root_dir, filename)
    # rest of your code
```

Comment: Yup, that was the next thing I just tried and it worked. Thanks for the documentation!